# Are these spaces homotopy equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be the wedge sum of two circles in $\mathbb{R^2}$, connected together at a point labelled $x_0$.
Let $Y$ be the union of two disjoint circles and a line segment joining both together.

Are these homeomorphic? Homotopy equivalent?

It looks like they have the same fundamental group, namely the free group on 2 elements. On the other hand it doesn't feel like I can give a homotopy equivalence from $X$ to $Y$, since there would be discontinuity at $x_0$.

**More precisely:**

Let $S(x,r)$ denote the circle of radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ centered at $(x,0) \in \mathbb{R^2}$.

Then $X$ is $S(-1,1) \cup S(1,1)$ and $Y$ is $S(-2,1) \cup [-1,1] \cup S(2,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are definitely homotopy equivalent:  retract the connecting line down to a point.

They are definitely not homeomorphic.  If they were, any homeo would preserve cut-points (points whose removal results in a disconnected space).  But the figure 8 has only one cut-point, the circles-with-line has many.

Comment: Thank you, I am having trouble constructing an explicit homotopy equivalence from X to Y though.

I can define an obvious map f on all of the figure 8 except at the single cut point. But where do I send the cut point? No matter where on the line segment of Y I try to send it, f is not continuous. What am I missing?

Comment: A point is homotopy equivalent to a closed interval.  Can you write this equivalence down?  Now do the same but "dangle" your circles at the ends.

Comment: I tried, but for some reason it stops being a homotopy equivalence once I dangle the circles.

Say I send the cut point $x_0$ of the figure 8 to the intersection point $y_0$ of the left circle and the horizontal line segment in $Y$. Then I can find a small open neighborhood of $y_0$ inside $Y$ (for example it extends no further than halfway across the line segment), whose pre-image in $X$ is not open since it does not contain any point of the right loop of the figure 8 other than $x_0$.

Comment: You could "pinch" a portion of one of the circles into a double cover of the interval.  (Though this doesn't quite feel like the "right" formalization of Randall's answer, as that was keeping the circles invariant in the informal description.  But it should still work as a homotopy inverse to the map $Y \to X$ which translates the circles and maps the segment to a constant point.)

Comment: Ahh, that sounds good! Thank you

Comment: I figured if we waited long enough someone would make the right suggestion.